# Fabric (hyperledger) explorer: refused to connect wss because of Content Security Policy on safari

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-explorer

I have a question/issue: I deploy the Hyperledger Explorer (connected to my Fabric network) via Kubernetes and connect to its ui via ingress. On any browser other than safari I have no issue with the explorer, but on Safari, after login, I have a blank page and the following error in the console of the browser:

```
[Error] Refused to connect to wss://[MYURL] because it appears in neither the connect-src directive nor the default-src directive of the Content Security Policy. (x2)
```

Do you have an idea if it's an issue with the explorer or with my ingress config? Is it some kind of cors issue?

This is my ingress config. I tried to modify the annotations, remove some, with no luck.

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  annotations:
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: MYURL
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/target: MYURL
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-headers: DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Authorization,X-Apollo-Tracing
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-credentials: "true"
  path: /
  servicePort: ui
  hosts:
    - MYURL
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's a safari bug:

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=201591

> As per CSP spec paragraph 6.6.2.6, point 4. `self` match, 2nd match >condition ([https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#match-url-to-source->expression](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#match-url-to-source-%3Eexpression)):
>
> *"'self'", return "Matches" if one or more of the following conditions is met:*
>
> *2. origin’s host is the same as url’s host, origin’s port and url’s port are either the same or the default ports for their respective schemes, and one or more of the following conditions is met:*
>
> - *url’s scheme is "https" or "wss*"
> - *origin’s scheme is "http" and url’s scheme is "http" or "ws"*
>
> This appears to not be working correctly in Safari, where I have a CSP of "connect-src 'self'" for a service worker, but the service worker refuses to connect to a web socket on the same host and port, logging error
>
> *Refused to connect to wss://SOMEHOST/ws because it does not appear in the connect-src directive of the Content Security Policy.*
>
> Chromium had the same issue, fixed about a year ago: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=815142
>
> Related W3C CSP Issue: https://github.com/w3c/webappsec-csp/issues/7

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers) Edit your answer :)

Comment: @Droid This wasn't a link-only Answer. Saying "Apparently it's a safari bug:" is an Answer. Adding the link as reference shouldn't be a disadvantage to the poster.